# Dependencies not being imported into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, module, dependencies, jupyter

I have a Python file called blob.py and a Jupyter Notebook f.ipynb. They are contained in the same folder.

blob.py

```
    import random 

    Class Blob()
```

f.ipynb

```
   import blob

   blob=Blob()
```

And I get the following error NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: What version of Python?  Is there anymore to blob.py ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.4. It appears that the %run blob command worked. Do you know an explanation as to why this worked and not import blob?

Comment: Are the two statements in one cell or two?